# svg spaceship game movement 2d

Tags: javascript, movement, html-canvas

I've been searching for a way to make an svg box move to all directions using js. I have seen many tutorials on how to do it grid like, but I want it so have a square that can turn, move forward, backwards and sideways. In terms of movement, I want to be like https://www.chromeexperiments.com/experiment/arena5 except there will be a square instead of a triangle and there will be no enemies.

My problem is that I don't know how to make an svg square move fluidly and without a grid, but the movement will only use keyboard, no mouse. Please be patient I'm new to js gaming.

Here is the most reason version of what I've trying, this is svg, right now I'm trying to make it in canvas.http://codepen.io/julian-a-avar/pen/PqZvxp

Comment: Why don't you make just a fluid movement? Moving it in squares will need probably more work. You can just use regular js DOM movement.

Comment: @Trader Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle example? Maybe I could then code you some kind of solution.

Comment: @Trader Example of what I'm woring right now?

Comment: Yes, a small example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Trader I added my work till now in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your example, you can now rotate using the keys, it uses CSS3 rotations.

If you want to move more fluid, you can either update the move() faster, or add some easing animations.

You can still make several improvements, but here is one solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPraGK

The css rotation code:

```
$("#block_green").css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)','-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)','-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)','transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)'});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! But, I'm kind of new to css3. I've noticed that the axis of rotation seems to be at coords(0, 0) of the svg, how can I set the axis of rotation right in the middle of the ship?